# PowerMockito.verifyStatic method does not work

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to use `PowerMockito` in order to test a static method in my service. I have the following test method:

```
@PrepareForTest(LoggingUtils.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class SiteServiceImplTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {

        // code omitted

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class);

        Page<SiteDTO> result = siteService.findAll(request, sort);

        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(LoggingUtils.class, Mockito.times(1));
    }
}
```

But when I run this test, it throws the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException:
> Argument passed to verify() is of type Class and is not a mock!
> Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
> See the examples of correct verifications:
>
>  verify(mock).someMethod();
>
>  verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
>
>  verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();

So, how can I use `PowerMockito` and test my static method?

The static method is as following:

```
LoggingUtils.info("The ...);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verification of a static method is done in two steps:

1. First call `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Static.class)` to start verifying behavior and then
2. Call the static method of the `Static.class` to verify.

For example:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Static.class); // 1
Static.firstStaticMethod(param); // 2
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-verify-behavior)

Your test should look:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(LoggingUtils.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        // mock all the static methods in a class called "LoggingUtils"
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LoggingUtils.class);

        // execute your test
        ServiceSite siteService = new ServiceSite();
        siteService.find();

        // Different from Mockito, always use PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Class) first
        // to start verifying behavior
        PowerMockito.verifyStatic(LoggingUtils.class, Mockito.times(1));
        // IMPORTANT:  Call the static method you want to verify
        LoggingUtils.info(anyString());
    }
}

public class ServiceSite {
    SiteDTO find() {
        LoggingUtils.info("123");
        return new SiteDTO();
    }
}
```

Comment: While I call `siteService.find();` and it calls `LoggingUtils.info("123")` line, why do I need to call `LoggingUtils.info(anyString());` extra? I coulc not understand it. Any idea?

Comment: In such way, you specify what static method you need to verify for behavior. Construction verify(Object).method(anyString()) is just splitted to two method calls in PowerMockito for static methods. Please review the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, voted up. But although  read the documentation and exactly tried what you suggested, but `PowerMockito.verifyStatic(LoggingUtils.class, Mockito.times(1));` line throws "*Argument passed to verify() is of type Class and is not a mock!*" error. Any suggestion please?

Comment: Please ensure that org.mockito has not added into dependencies in your project.
<groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
<artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
You must have dependencies only on PowerMock.

Comment: Probably it is a bug in PowerMock please review: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992. What version do you use?

Comment: Hmmm, actually I also need mockito. Then, should I use this annotation at the top of my test class? `@PowerMockIgnore({"org.mockito.*"})` ? Otherwise how can I use `when().then()` etc. methods for stubbing other parts of my testing method?

Comment: I use v`2.0.9`  for bıth `powermock-api-mockito2` and `powermock-module-junit4` (I use JUnit 4).

Comment: On the other hand, I also tried almost all of the workarounds on https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/992, but still the same problem.

Comment: try to use mokito core version 3.3.3 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2/2.0.9

Comment: Just FYI, I also tried `mockito-core v3.3.3`, but still the same error. Then I gave up as there seems to be a bug, because I  followed exactly the same approach mentioned on documentation and the workarounds. Thanks a lot again, I do not want to take your more time.

Comment: The last recommendation is to debug mokito via IntelliJ, you can download sources directly from IDE. The method to check is org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.isMock(Object mock). It should use correct MockMaker for static methods mocking.  Probably debug can help to understand the root cause.

Comment: Hmm, I never debug any library, but if you shared necessary steps briefly, I will and it will be so useful for me.

Comment: Enable sources to download from maven repository https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207280165-How-can-I-force-Idea-to-download-all-sources-of-all-Maven-artifacts-  and then just perform Step Into library method.

Comment: Very useful tips, thanks a lot again. Voted up ;)

Comment: `PowerMockito.verifyStatic()` accepts an object of type `VerificationMode`. You cannot provide a class like that.